# AWS load balancing based on query string

Tags: http, amazon-web-services, nginx, load-balancing

I have two servers behind a AWS ELB. The request sent to the ELB looks like:

> Http: //URL?server_id=xxx

where xxx specifies the server the client request should be distributed to.

So is it possible for AWS ELB to do load balancing based on query string?

If it's not possible, can I achieve this using Nginx server? I'd very appreciate it if someone could give me an example on how to configure AWS ELB or Nginx load balancing.

Comment: see [this nginx load balancing question](http://serverfault.com/questions/475875/nginx-load-balancing-based-on-url-and-not-ip-address) on SE. What you are doing is.. weird, though.

Answer (score 0):

No, its not possible for ELB to do that. ELB uses [Least Outstanding Request](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/TerminologyandKeyConcepts.html#request-routing) algorithm